# Expression did not evaluate to a constant two level constexpr functions (compiler bug?)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr, compile-time-constant

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
template<int I>
class A
{
public:
    inline constexpr static int size() { return I; }
};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr auto size(const T& arg) noexcept -> decltype(arg.size())
{
    return arg.size();
}

template<typename T>
inline constexpr void twoLevel(const T& arg) noexcept
{
    static_assert(size(arg) > 0);
}

int main()
{
    A<5> a;
    static_assert(size(a)>0); //this works
    twoLevel(a); // this does not
    return 0;
}
```

Which fails to compile on msvc with the error `expression did not evaluate to a constant`, but works with gcc. Is it gcc accepting something that's undefined behaviour? Or is it a compiler bug on msvc's part?
Here's a demo: [godbolt code](https://godbolt.org/z/CUbdR7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [[expr.const]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4):

> An expression `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - [...]
> - an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>
>   - it is usable in constant expressions or
>   - its lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;
> - [...]

In:

```
static_assert(size(arg) > 0);
```

We have an *id-expression* that refers to a variable of reference type, and the reference does not have preceding initialization, so we do not have a constant expression.

I think this:

```
static_assert(size(a) > 0);
```

works because of "preceding initialization" - we enter constant evaluation by directly binding the reference `arg` to the variable `a`, whereas in the other case we're binding a reference to another reference.

Both should work if you take by value though.

Comment: So gcc shouldn't compile this either? Won't passing it by value make a copy though - is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: An initialization of a function parameter does count as a preceding initialization, or else the final line `constexpr int y = h(1);` of the example in the same paragraph could not be valid. The issue is that `a` is not "usable in constant expressions" and its lifetime did not begin within evaluation of `size(arg) > 0`.

Comment: @aschepler Is there any way to mitigate this problem, without passing the object by value? Since I do not want the object copied (it may contain a large static array).

Comment: @aschepler That doesn't help me for my use case - I specifically needed a free function since I want to be able to define a specialization for structures (like plain arrays), that works even if they do not provide a size static method.

Comment: @lightxbulb Then define a trait struct, which can be explicitly and partially specialized?

Comment: @aschepler I was trying to avoid code duplication - I know how to deal with this if I don't use the above, it's just I felt it was inelegant duplicating code, especially when I feel like when everything is constant, it should be treated as such - but it seems my intuition disagrees with the standard (though gcc compiles this for some reason).